# =MATCH() equivalent for multidimensional ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet, where cells A1-C20=`=INT(RAND()*10)`.  This is my data range.  Cell E1=1, E2=2, E3=3, etc.  These are the values I am trying to find.  I set cell F1=`=MATCH(E1,A:C,0)`, F2=`=MATCH(E1,A:C,0)`, etc.

However, all the `MATCH` functions return `#N/A`, because the input range is multi-dimensional.  How can I test whether a given value (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) exists in a multidimensional range (A1-C20)?

/edit:  [This function](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ultimate-excel-lookup-function.htm) works, but is more than I need.  Is there any way to make it return just TRUE or FALSE, depending on if the lookup value is in the range?

```
Function OzgridLookup(Find_Val As Variant, Occurrence As Long, Table_Range As Range, _
 Offset_Cols As Long, Optional Column_Lookin As Long, Optional Row_Offset As Long) As Variant

Dim lLoop As Long
Dim FoundCell As Range

    If Column_Lookin = 0 Then 'No column # specified
        With Table_Range
            'Top left cell has Find_Val & Occurrence is 1
            If Table_Range.Cells(1, 1) = Find_Val And Occurrence = 1 Then
              OzgridLookup = .Cells(1, 1)(1, Offset_Cols + 1)
              Exit Function 'All done :)
            Else 'No column # specified so search all for _
                    nth Occurrence reading left to right
             Set FoundCell = .Cells(1, 1) 'Set cell variable for Find start
                For lLoop = 1 To Occurrence 'Loop as many times as Occurrences _
                 and each time Set "FoundCell" to start next Find from
                  Set FoundCell = _
                        Table_Range.Find(What:=Find_Val, After:=FoundCell, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                Next lLoop
            End If
        End With
    Else 'column # specified
      With Table_Range.Columns(Column_Lookin) 'Work with column # specified
        Set FoundCell = .Cells(1, 1) 'Set cell variable for Find start
            For lLoop = 1 To Occurrence 'Loop as many times as Occurrences _
                 and each time Set "FoundCell" to start next Find from
                  Set FoundCell = _
                        Table_Range.Find(What:=Find_Val, After:=FoundCell, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Next lLoop
      End With
    End If

    OzgridLookup = FoundCell.Offset(Row_Offset, Offset_Cols)

End Function
```

Comment: It should be noted that Match CAN handle unsorted arrays.  However, Match does not work on multi-dimensional arrays, i.e., you can't use multiple columns as the search range (What index could it return?).  That's the source of the error.

Comment: @Excellll: I edited my question to reflect this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use COUNTIF to do this since you only want to know whether the number is present (not its location).

```
=COUNTIF(A:C,E1)>0
```

This will return "TRUE" if it is present, "FALSE" if it is not.

Just for fun, here's a worksheet function solution that returns the cell address that matches the lookup value.  It uses the fact that you are only searching in 3 columns.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E1,A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E1,B:B,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E1,C:C,0)),"Not found.","C"&MATCH(E1,C:C,0)),"B"&MATCH(E1,B:B,0)),"A"&MATCH(E1,A:A,0))
```

I thought I'd also throw in a VBA solution that can return the match location inside a (contiguous) range. It looks at columns one at a time from left to right and returns the address of the first match found.

```
Public Function MDMATCH(srchfor As String, lookin As Range) As String

Application.Volatile
Dim RngArray() As Variant
Dim topleft As String
Dim tmpval As String

topleft = lookin.Address
topleft = Left(topleft, InStr(topleft, ":") - 1)
tmpval = "Not found."
RngArray = lookin

For i = 1 To UBound(RngArray, 2)
    If tmpval = "Not found." Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(RngArray, 1)
            If RngArray(j, i) = srchfor Then
                tmpval = Range(topleft).Offset(j - 1, i - 1).Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
MDMATCH = tmpval
End Function
```