# Excel 2013 Match Function Throwing #N/A

Tags: excel-2013

I have the following in range C1:D6 -

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
6   F
7   G
8   H
```

The formula `=MATCH(6,C1:D6,0)` returns #N/A.  I've searched this and other forums without success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to search in a multi-dimensional range but i found a workaround in another Question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7179926/2732272

Comment: Thanks, Patrick.  It turns out I only need to use Match in a single-column range of cells -- that seems to be working as desired.