# Excel: search value in array and fetch row and column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a spreadsheet of available samples across 45 boxes, arranged stacked with column headers from 1 to 10 and row headers from A to J. I'm looking for a way to fetch the box, row and cell number if I lookup an ID (prefixed with B).

**`Sheet 1`** is a list of animal IDs that I want to know if a sample is available for

### `Sheet 2`:

```
Box 1
     1     2      3     4     5 ... 10
A   B43   B12    B3    B6    B103
B   B13   B14    B78   B51   B63
C   B78   B33    B99   B43   B92
...
J
Box 2
     1     2      3     4     5 ... 10
A    B2    B6
```

I have tried doing nested if functions by columns:

```
if(match(A2, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$521,0),"1",if(match(A2,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$521,0),"2","")
```

...but I've been getting `#N/A` if `A2` is in column `C`.

I've resorted to re-labelling the left-most column to `Box 1 A`, `Box 1 B`, `Box 1 C`... so on, and doing:

```
=index(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$521,match(A2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$521,0),0)
```

...and duplicating the function for **Columns 1 to 10*.

### `Sheet 1`:

```
Animal ID   Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4 ...
B12         .       Box 1 A     .         .
B43         .         .         .         Box 1 C
...
```

Is there an easier way to fetch the location of a sample from an array?

Comment: Hi Pam, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you clarify what you mean by `box, row and cell number`?  Are the "boxes" also various worksheets?  ( I assume so since Boxes 1 & 2 both have a cell `A1`.)

Comment: ...also can you share more of an example of what the "correct result" would be in some of these cases?  It's confusing since it seems like you have sheets-within-sheets, plus the data your looking up looks like cell references (ie, **'B6' is in 'A2', and 'B63' is in 'B5'**).

Comment: Thank for the welcome! All 45 boxes are on one worksheet, stacked on each other, with rows being A-J (re-labeled box+row e.g Box 3 H, Box 39 B etc.) and columns from 1-10. And yes unfortunately they do end up looking like cell references because the physical boxes are labelled in that way. I was thinking of getting one column on Sheet 1 for box+row number and another column for column number, but I welcome any other suggestions

Comment: I'm afraid I''m still having trouble picturing what you're starting with and what you need (If I understood that, the *"how to"* is probably the easy part!) -- but I'm intrigued!  Does @hellboy 's answer (below) cover what you need?

Comment: ...if not, are we talking about an *actual **physical** sectioned **"box"***, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaeqQ.jpg , storing samples of something, that you're trying to organize into a *list*?

Comment: Yup it is boxes for blood/DNA samples, so physical boxes https://4.imimg.com/data4/WL/GE/MY-5773836/cryo-box-pp-500x500.jpg

Comment: His answer does help, but I think it might be easier to get results with columns: [Animal ID]-[Box]-[Row]-[Column]. 
Once I use up the blood/DNA samples I'll have to change Sheet2, so I was looking for an automated way for the spreadsheet to update. I usually have a subset of animals that I'm looking for so it'd be so much easier than having to manually find them in Sheet2 each time.

Comment: *Neat!*  Okay so, all of this data is contained within columns `A` to `K` of a *single* worksheet with **45 identical 10x10 grids**, and the *2nd row before each grid* is a name like `Box 23` (so all the names are in column `A`...  and (for example): *`A1` of Box would "always" be in worksheet cell `B42`*, right?  The exact solution depends on details like that,but I suspect that [this VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7179115/8112776) (called from the worksheet as an alternative to `MATCH` will be at least *part* of your solution, along with `OFFSET(…)` and `=ASC(…)`.

Comment: Did you mean Box 1 A1 (i.e cell B3) would always be animal B43? The worksheet is laid out like Hellboy's post. Thank you I'll have a look :-)

Comment: Well, my point with the example was: the boxes are always 12 rows tall and 11 rows wide (including headings, like Hellboy's post), so there is an "A1" at ***worksheet cells* B3, B15, B27**, etc..?  I just wanted to confirm that the worksheet is in an *exact* pattern before figuring out the "magic formula". :-)  Alternatively, have you considered using Microsoft Access?  This will work in Excel but Access is in many ways better suited to this sort of data management (and not as complicated to learn as some think!)

Comment: Yup that is correct. I've just realised another problem - if a sample occurs twice in the same column but in a different box. Do you have any suggestions on how to better organise my data? I have not tried Microsoft Access yet but I could give it a go if you reckon it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Sheet2` looks like this.

[image]

and you want the data like this in `Sheet1`.

[image]

Then enter this formula in Cell `B2` of `Sheet1` and drag it down and across.

```
=IFERROR(CONCATENATE(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,(MATCH($A2,Sheet2!B:B,0))-MOD(MATCH($A2,Sheet2!B:B,0)-1,12),)," - ",INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!B:B,0))),".")
```